# multiple languages in extension helper class seems not working

Tags: magento, translation, multiple-languages

I want to support multiple languages in the helper class of extension, but it seems not working.

Here is the code in a function of `helper/data.php`:

```
if($level == 1) return $html.' '.$this->__("All Categories");
```

I followed this article: http://www.magentothemess.com/archives/912 to support multiple languages, but failed.

Comment: what does mean "not working" ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it because I has not disabled cache.